# Haskell Couldn't match type

Tags: haskell

The program is suppose to deal with student in university

```
data Etudiant = Etudiant CodePermanent Nom Prenom CodeProgramme deriving Show
data Inscription = Inscription CodePermanent Sigle NoGroupe CodeSession Date Date Note deriving (Show, Eq)

getCodePermanent :: Etudiant -> CodePermanent
getCodePermanent (Etudiant codePermanent _ _ _) = codePermanent

listeInscription :: Inscription -> Bool
listeInscription (Inscription _ _ _ codeSession _ _ _) = codeSession == 32003

filtreInscription1 :: [Inscription] -> [Inscription]
filtreInscription1 linscription = filter listeInscription linscription

getNoGroupe2 :: Inscription -> NoGroupe
getNoGroupe2 (Inscription _ _ noGroupe _ _ _ _) = noGroupe

numGroupesCoursEtu :: [Inscription] -> Etudiant -> [NoGroupe]
numGroupesCoursEtu listeInscr etu = map getNoGroupe2(filter (\x -> getCodePermanent(x) == getCodePermanent(etu)) listeInscr)
```

The goal of the fonctions here is to extract from the list [Inscription] a list [NoGroupe] that match the session code 32003 and the id of the student : CodePermanent

My last line of code gives back an error with the types... Can you guys see the problem?

the error :

```
TP1.hs:115:54: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘Etudiant’ with ‘Inscription’
  Expected type: [Inscription]
    Actual type: [Etudiant]
• In the second argument of ‘map’, namely
    ‘(filter
        (\ x -> getCodePermanent (x) == getCodePermanent (etu))
        listeInscr)’
  In the expression:
    map
      getNoGroupe2
      (filter
         (\ x -> getCodePermanent (x) == getCodePermanent (etu)) listeInscr)
  In an equation for ‘numGroupesCoursEtu’:
      numGroupesCoursEtu listeInscr etu
        = map
            getNoGroupe2
            (filter
               (\ x -> getCodePermanent (x) == getCodePermanent (etu)) listeInscr)

TP1.hs:115:114: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘Inscription’ with ‘Etudiant’
  Expected type: [Etudiant]
    Actual type: [Inscription]
• In the second argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘listeInscr’
  In the second argument of ‘map’, namely
    ‘(filter
        (\ x -> getCodePermanent (x) == getCodePermanent (etu))
        listeInscr)’
  In the expression:
    map
      getNoGroupe2
      (filter
         (\ x -> getCodePermanent (x) == getCodePermanent (etu)) listeInscr)
```

line 115 is the last line of code numGroupesCoursEtu.....

Comment: Did you try to read the error message carefully? If so what is confusing you about it?

Comment: I dont understand how to make them match...

Comment: What should `getCodePermanent` do when passed an `Inscription`? What does your code say? When you call `getCodePermanent (etu)`, you are passing `getCodePermanent` a __list__ of `Inscription`s, but it expects a single `Etudiant`.

Comment: Ok my goal is to get the group course number(noGroupe) of the student x (passed in parameter : Etudiant) for the semester code 32003 (codeSession = 32003).
So first i have to get the list of course that have as semester code : 32003
And then in that list i have to locate the codePermanent that matches the Etudiant passed in parameter of numGroupeCoursEtu to finally get the list of the course number (NoCours) that the student is following

Comment: `numGroupesCoursEtu` does to much in a single line. Break it apart and implement each step in your previous comment each as a top level function. When you get it working you can put these functions into a where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getCodePermanent :: Etudiant -> CodePermanent

Note that `getCodePermanent` takes a `Etudiant` as a parameter.

```
(\x -> getCodePermanent(x) == getCodePermanent(etu))
```

Presumably you are trying to check if a `Inscription` has the same `CodePermanent` as the given `Etudiant`. But as I said earlier, `getCodePermanent` takes a `Etudiant` as a parameter. You need to write another function to get the `CodePermanent` from a `Inscription`.

Comment: Thanks! i add those two lines : getCodePermanent2 :: Inscription -> CodePermanent
getCodePermanent2 (Inscription codePermanent _ _ _ _ _ _) = codePermanent
And now its working!

Comment: @JiaMingWang that is the idea. Although, I suggest finding a better name.

Comment: @JiaMingWang please remember to accept my answer when you are able